# Remove icon which displays or hides the left sidebar in shinydashboard for a certain tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny dashboard below in which I would like to hide the icon in the left part of the header which if pushed hides or display the left sidebar. Is that possible to hide it only when Im in the "Front" tab?

[image]

```
# app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
                            enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
                            rightSidebarIcon = "gears",
                            fixed = T
                            )

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  dbHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      id ="tabA",
      type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
      tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table")
      )
    )
  ),
  rightsidebar = rightSidebar()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (input$tabA == "Front") {
      hide(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
      addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
      removeClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
    } else {
      show(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
      removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
      addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to hide the icon you can do this with the help of some Javascript code. In order to insert the JS code in Shiny, one must use `tags$script()`.

So in order to hide the icon, insert below code inside `dashboardBody()`

```
   # Note: 'sidebar-toggle' is a class name (i.e. HTML class attribute) of Shiny icon 
   tags$script("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';"),
```

And the output is:
[image]

More on inserting JS in Shiny can be found here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html

**UPDATED**

If you want to hide the icon only when the user is in the "Front" tab you can do this again by inserting some JS code, but this time you can insert it inside server side part (i.e. inside your `observe` function).

So you need to insert the JS part which will hide the icon if tab "Front" is pressed

```
  shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';")
```

and the part which will show the icon, if tab "Data" is pressed

```
  shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';")
```

So your whole code looks like this

```
# app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "gears",
  fixed = T
)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  dbHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      id ="tabA",
      type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
      tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table")
      )
    )
  ),
  rightsidebar = rightSidebar()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (input$tabA == "Front") {
      hide(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
      addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
      removeClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';")


    } else {
      show(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
      removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
      addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';")

    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: hey Im sorry but I forgot to ask in my initial Q.I edited.Is that possible to hide it only when Im in the "Front" tab?

Comment: Please see my modified answer.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: coyld a similar logic applied to this one?if u have time to check I would be thankful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895748/display-different-image-as-title-of-shiny-dashboard-based-on-different-tabpanels

Comment: I will check today.